# recursive array for duplicate shell programs

Tags: shell

It appears I have done this before but cant recollect at the right moment. All i want is run 3 instances of same script feeding off of single array traversing dates. 

`for i in 1..10
do 
bash a.sh $i
bash a.sh $i
done.`

I want the a.sh to grab 1 for the first script , 2 for the second one and if 1 finishes the run then grab 3 and then 4 etc. Basically two identical scrpts are working on looping through dates

Any help is appreciated.